# Copy column data from multiple sheets to one sheet in the same column, no overwriting

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I have three data extracts:

- Invoices
- CreditNotes
- Journals

I have created an Excel workbook that has this data in three separate tabs. Each tab has over 50 columns.

What I want to do is create a 'master' tab that copies just three columns of data from each of these three tabs into one consolidated worksheet, i.e. with the columns:

- Account code
- Unit amount
- Date

I know how to copy entire columns from one sheet to another using VBA, I just don't know how to copy another column's worth of data to the next blank cell on the 'master tab, i.e. not overwrite the data, e.g.:

I can copy the account code data from the 'Invoices' tab to the 'master' tab, but then when I go to copy the account code data from the 'CreditNotes' tab it overwrites what I've already copies from the Invoices tab, whereas I want it to be copied underneath.

Sorry for the wall of text, I'm just trying to provide as much information as possible!

The code I have is:

```
Sub Consolidation()

Sheets("Invoices").Columns(11).Copy Destination:=Sheets("master").Columns(1)
Sheets("CreditNotes").Columns(11).Copy Destination:=Sheets("master").Columns(1)
Sheets("Journals").Columns(11).Copy Destination:=Sheets("master").Columns(1)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Consolidate Column

```vb
Sub ConsolidateColumn()

    ' Source Worksheet List
    Const cSheets As String = "Invoices,CreditNotes,Journals"
    Const cTarget As String = "Sheet1"  ' Target Worksheet Name
    Const cFur As Long = 2              ' Source First Used Row
    Const cColS As Variant = 11         ' Source Column Letter/Number ("K")
    Const cColT As Variant = 1          ' Target Column Letter/Number ("A")

    Dim rng As Range      ' Source Column Range (in current Source Worksheet)
    Dim vntW As Variant   ' Worksheet Array
    Dim LurS As Long      ' Source Last Used Row Number
    Dim FerT As Long      ' Target First Empty Row Number
    Dim i As Long         ' Worksheet Array Element Counter

    ' Split Source Worksheet List to Worksheet Array.
    vntW = Split(cSheets, ",")

    ' In This Workbook (The Workbook Containing This Code)
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cTarget)
        ' Loop through elements of Worksheet Array.
        For i = 0 To UBound(vntW)
            ' Calculate Target First Empty Row Number.
            FerT = .Cells(.Rows.Count, cColT).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            ' In Current Source Worksheet
            With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Trim(vntW(i)))
                ' Calculate Source Last Used Row Number.
                LurS = .Cells(.Rows.Count, cColS).End(xlUp).Row
                ' Calculate Source Column Range.
                ' Create a reference to Source Column Range.
                Set rng = .Cells(cFur, cColS).Resize(LurS - cFur + 1)
            End With
            ' Calculate Target Column Range.
            ' Copy values from current Source Column Range to Target Column
            ' Range.
            .Cells(FerT, cColT).Resize(rng.Rows.Count) = rng.Value
        Next
    End With
 End Sub
```